# DateTime getting todays Month in if statement

Tags: c#

I want to do an if statement if month == january for example load something
else if month == april load something else.
Can someone help please 
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `Month` property, range is 1-12:

```
int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
if(month == 4) //April
{..
```

Answer (score 3):

```
switch (DateTime.Now.Month)
{
     case 1: // JAN
        ...
        break;
     case 2: // FEB
        ...
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ways

```
if(DateTime.Today.Month == 1){
  // do something
}

if(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(dateTime.Month) == "January"){
  // do something
}
```

for the second method you will need to include System.Globalization

Answer (score 2):

You can create an Enum with the Months of the year like this:

```
public enum Months{
     January = 1,
     February = 2,
     .
     .
     December = 12
}
```

And try

```
if(Datetime.Now.Month == (int)Months.January){

  //Do Something...

} else if(Datetime.Now.Month == (int)Months.April){

  //Do Something else

}
```

Hope this helps. Regards,

Juan Alvarez

Answer (score 1):

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var monthName = now.ToString("MMMM")
if (monthName == "January)
{
  //load something 
}
else if (monthName == "April")
{
  //load something else. 
}
```

Comment: Will there be a problem with computers set up in a non-english culture with this though? Would they not return a different string?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DateTime.Month](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month.aspx) property to check month

```
switch (DateTime.Now.Month){
  case 1://January stuff here
  break;
  case 2://Feb stuff here etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Is there a predefined enumeration for Month in the .NET library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899565/is-there-a-predefined-enumeration-for-month-in-the-net-library).

```
string monthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat
    .GetMonth ( DateTime.Now.Month );

switch (monthName)
{
    case "January":
        // do something
        break;
    case "April":
        // do something
        break;
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These should help -

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-month

[Get the previous month's first and last day dates in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591752/get-the-previous-months-first-and-last-day-dates-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

```
string monthName = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
if(monthName == "april"{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.Now.Month

```
        if(DateTime.Now.Month == 1)
        {
            //January
        }
        else if (DateTime.Now.Month == 2)
        {
            //February
        }
        //etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an enum for Month and use this case statement

```
switch (DateTime.Now.Month)
{
     case MonthEnum.JAN
        break;
}
```