# Set Textbox value to last month

Tags: c#, textbox

How do i set the textbox value to last day of last month(to end of previous month), using today's date.

for example:

if today is 23/03/2012 textbox value should be 29/02/2012
if come next month and date is 12/04/2012 then textbox value should be 31/03/2012 and so on

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the previous month's first and last day dates in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591752/get-the-previous-months-first-and-last-day-dates-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Ha... got 4 duplicates just inside this question.  Take your pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the first day of the current month and subtract 1:

```
DateTime value = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddDays(-1);
textBox1.Text = date.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime.DaysInMonth to accomplish this:

```
var daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month - 1);
var lastDayInMonth = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month - 1, daysInMonth);
textBox1.Text = lastDayInMonth.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the first day of the month and subtract one day.

```
DateTime lastDayOfThePreviousMonth = dateSelected.AddDays(-dateSelected.Day);
```

Comment: Curious.. What if the current day is 1?  Would it then Add -0 days?

Comment: @ChrisGessler you are right, no need to subtract one from the days. I have updated.

Answer (score 0):

In C#:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1).AddDays(-1);
```

Then call `.ToString()` and pass in whatever format you like.