# DateTime manipulation

Tags: c#, datetime

Here is my code:

```
DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime( orderDate ).AddMonths(-1);
DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime( orderDate );
```

orderDate is a valid date I pass in.

How do I always guarantee startDate is the first day of the previous month for orderDate?
How do I always guarantee endDate is the last day of the month for orderDate?

Example:

```
orderDate = 5/4/2012

I want startDate to be 4/1/2012 (or 04/1/2012 whichever is default)
I want endDate to be 4/30/2012
```

How can I acheive this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the previous month's first and last day dates in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591752/get-the-previous-months-first-and-last-day-dates-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Why are you converting a DateTime to a DateTime?

Comment: @TimeSchmelter Because orderDate is a string passed in from two parameters that can be changed via a text box or query string.

Comment: @JamesWilson: I've just asked because you've said that _"orderDate is a valid date I pass in"_ and there's really [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ex62041.aspx) which takes a DateTime.

Comment: There is no 4/31/2012 :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter well it is a valid date, perhaps I should have been more specific.  I'm still new to asp.net.  So orderDate is a string version of a specific date.  Keeping me on my toes is always a good thing! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime( orderDate ).AddMonths(-1);
// set to first of month
startDate = startDate.AddDays(1-startDate.Day);

// Set end date to last of month, which is one day before first of next month
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: I'm going with this method.  Any chance this can break on December or January like one other answer in this thread?  Just want to cover all my bases I can.

Comment: @James Wilson - as with any code you pull off SO there are no guarantees :)  Unless it's baked into your ASP.NET project you should write unit tests for it.  In any case you should definitely test as many fringe cases as you can think of (dates in January, December, 2000, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

```
origDate = startDate.AddMonths(-1);
DateTime myDate = new DateTime(origDate.Year, origDate.Month, 1);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x.aspx

Something like this... We do it often enough that we've just created an extension method on date.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime( orderDate.Month == 1 ? orderDate.Year - 1 : orderDate.Year, orderDate.Month - 1, 1);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(orderDate.Year, orderDate.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(orderDate.Year, OrderDate.Month));
```

Comment: -1 What if your date is in January? You will have the wrong year. I'll remove downvote if answer is corrected.

Comment: I removed my downvote, but I don't think the conditional operator is necessary here.

Comment: No, I mean there are a handful of ways this can be done. I was trying to cram it into one line lol

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime constructor that takes separate values for each year, month, day,... and adjust them accodringly (i.e. first of the month means day = 1).

Answer (score 0):

```
var orderDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
var endDate = orderDate.AddDays(-orderDate.Day);
var startDate  = endDate.AddDays(-(endDate.Day - 1));
```